# How to convert a tree-like structure to a plain HTML table using rowspans?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

Given a structure of nodes from different data sources where one node depends on *0 to n* other nodes but a single node can only depend on nodes from one source

```
const nodes = [
    { dataSourceId: "a", id: "a-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: undefined, dependsOnNodes: [] },
    { dataSourceId: "a", id: "a-2", dependsOnDataSourceId: undefined, dependsOnNodes: [] },
    { dataSourceId: "a", id: "a-3", dependsOnDataSourceId: undefined, dependsOnNodes: [] },
    { dataSourceId: "b", id: "b-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: "a", dependsOnNodes: ["a-1"] },
    { dataSourceId: "b", id: "b-2", dependsOnDataSourceId: "a", dependsOnNodes: ["a-1"] },
    { dataSourceId: "b", id: "b-3", dependsOnDataSourceId: "a", dependsOnNodes: ["a-1", "a-2"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-1"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-2", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-3", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-4", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-5", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2", "b-3"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-6", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2", "b-3"] },
    { dataSourceId: "e", id: "e-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: "c", dependsOnNodes: ["c-1", "c-3"] },
    { dataSourceId: "e", id: "e-2", dependsOnDataSourceId: "c", dependsOnNodes: ["c-3"] },
    { dataSourceId: "self-reference", id: "a-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: "a", dependsOnNodes: ["a-1"] },
    { dataSourceId: "d", id: "d-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2"] },
    { dataSourceId: "d", id: "d-2", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2"] },
];
```

`nodes` is not sorted, the order is random (and should not matter).

I want to represent this structure as a HTML table using rowspans. What I know is the order of columns where each data source represents a column

`const dataSourceIds = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "self-reference"];`

The first item in `dataSourceIds` ( "a" ) always represents the group of root nodes.

First I tried to "draw" the **expected result**

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
      <th>d</th>
      <th>e</th>
      <th>self-reference</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="9">a-1</td>
      <td>b-1</td>
      <td>c-1</td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source d --></td>
      <td>e-1</td>
      <td>a-1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by a-1 rowspan --></td>
      <td rowspan="6">b-2</td>
      <td>c-2</td>
      <td>d-1</td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source e --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source self-reference --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by a-1 rowspan --></td>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by b-2 rowspan --></td>
      <td rowspan="2">c-3</td>
      <td>d-2</td>
      <td>e-1</td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source a-to-a --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by a-1 rowspan --></td>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by b-2 rowspan --></td>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by c-3 rowspan --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source d --></td>
      <td>e-2</td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source self-reference --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by a-1 rowspan --></td>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by b-2 rowspan --></td>
      <td>c-4</td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source d --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source e --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source self-reference --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by a-1 rowspan --></td>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by b-2 rowspan --></td>
      <td>c-5</td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source d --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source e --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source self-reference --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by a-1 rowspan --></td>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by b-2 rowspan --></td>
      <td>c-6</td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source d --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source e --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source self-reference --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by a-1 rowspan --></td>
      <td rowspan="2">b-3</td>
      <td>c-5</td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source d --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source e --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source self-reference --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by a-1 rowspan --></td>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by b-3 rowspan --></td>
      <td>c-6</td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source d --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source e --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source self-reference --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">a-2</td>
      <td rowspan="2">b-3</td>
      <td>c-5</td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source d --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source e --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source self-reference --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by a-2 rowspan --></td>
      <td style="display: none"><!-- Covered by b-3 rowspan --></td>
      <td>c-6</td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source d --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source e --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source self-reference --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a-3</td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source b --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source c --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source d --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source e --></td>
      <td><!-- Empty for source self-reference --></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**This is what I tried so far**

```js
const nodes = [
    { dataSourceId: "a", id: "a-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: undefined, dependsOnNodes: [] },
    { dataSourceId: "a", id: "a-2", dependsOnDataSourceId: undefined, dependsOnNodes: [] },
    { dataSourceId: "a", id: "a-3", dependsOnDataSourceId: undefined, dependsOnNodes: [] },
    { dataSourceId: "b", id: "b-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: "a", dependsOnNodes: ["a-1"] },
    { dataSourceId: "b", id: "b-2", dependsOnDataSourceId: "a", dependsOnNodes: ["a-1"] },
    { dataSourceId: "b", id: "b-3", dependsOnDataSourceId: "a", dependsOnNodes: ["a-1", "a-2"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-1"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-2", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-3", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-4", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-5", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2", "b-3"] },
    // breaks here because c-6 must also replace a-2 with a rowspan
    // { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-6", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2", "b-3"] },
    { dataSourceId: "e", id: "e-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: "c", dependsOnNodes: ["c-1", "c-3"] },
    { dataSourceId: "e", id: "e-2", dependsOnDataSourceId: "c", dependsOnNodes: ["c-3"] },
    { dataSourceId: "self-reference", id: "a-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: "a", dependsOnNodes: ["a-1"] },
    { dataSourceId: "d", id: "d-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2"] },
    // breaks here because b-2 must be added at c-3 but it tries to add it at c-2
    // { dataSourceId: "d", id: "d-2", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2"] },
];

const dataSourceIds = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "self-reference"];

// group the nodes by source so it's easier to inspect them
const groupedNodes = {};

for (const dataSourceId of dataSourceIds) {
    groupedNodes[dataSourceId] = nodes.filter(node => node.dataSourceId === dataSourceId);
}

// extract the root node id so dataSourceIds only contains child sources
const rootNodeId = dataSourceIds.shift();

const rootNodes = groupedNodes[rootNodeId];

let rows = [];

// setup the initial rows with root nodes
for (const rootNode of rootNodes) {
    const row = {
        [rootNodeId]: rootNode
    };

    for (const dataSourceId of dataSourceIds) {
        row[dataSourceId] = "empty";
    }

    rows.push(row);
}

// fill the rows with child nodes
for (let dataSourceIdIndex = 0; dataSourceIdIndex < dataSourceIds.length; dataSourceIdIndex++) {
    const dataSourceId = dataSourceIds[dataSourceIdIndex];
    const childNodes = groupedNodes[dataSourceId];

    for (const childNode of childNodes) {
        const { dependsOnDataSourceId, dependsOnNodes } = childNode;

        for (const parentNodeId of dependsOnNodes) {
            for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows.length; rowIndex++) {
                const row = rows[rowIndex];
                const parentNode = row[dependsOnDataSourceId];

                // parent node must exist in this row
                if (parentNode === "empty") {
                    continue;
                }

                // parent node id must match
                if (parentNode.id !== parentNodeId) {
                    continue;
                }

                // what if parent is covered?

                // simply add it if there is no value yet
                if (row[dataSourceId] === "empty") {
                    row[dataSourceId] = childNode;
                    continue;
                }

                // this row already has a value for this data source so we have to duplicate it
                const duplicatedRow = structuredClone(row);

                // replace the parent node with a rowspan
                duplicatedRow[dependsOnDataSourceId] = { coveredByRowIndex: rowIndex };

                // replace the previous child node with the current one
                duplicatedRow[dataSourceId] = childNode;

                // set all data source values between dependsOnDataSourceId ( exclusive ) and dataSourceIdIndex ( exclusive ) to empty because they are siblings with no data
                const dependsOnDataSourceIdIndex = dataSourceIds.findIndex(previousDataSourceId => previousDataSourceId === dependsOnDataSourceId);

                for (let emptyDataSourceIndex = dependsOnDataSourceIdIndex + 1; emptyDataSourceIndex < dataSourceIdIndex; emptyDataSourceIndex++) {
                    const emptyDataSourceId = dataSourceIds[emptyDataSourceIndex];
                    duplicatedRow[emptyDataSourceId] = "empty";
                }

                // check if there already are any covered rows
                const amountOfCoveredRows = rows.filter(rowToInspect => {
                    const dataSourceValue = rowToInspect[dependsOnDataSourceId];

                    if (dataSourceValue.coveredByRowIndex === undefined) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    return dataSourceValue.coveredByRowIndex === rowIndex;
                }).length;

                const insertDuplicatedRowIndex = rowIndex + amountOfCoveredRows + 1;

                // insert the new row after the last covered row
                const previousRows = rows.slice(0, insertDuplicatedRowIndex);
                const nextRows = rows.slice(insertDuplicatedRowIndex, rows.length);

                rows = [
                  ...previousRows,
                  duplicatedRow,
                  ...nextRows
                ];

                // but don't inspect this one in the next run
                rowIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(rows);
```

where

- `"empty"` means that the `<td>` element is empty
- `coveredByRowIndex` means that it should use `style="display: none"`

The code is inefficient but this shouldn't matter for now, I want to optimize it later.

As you can see `rows` does not contain the expected result yet. There are 2 nodes breaking the algorithm. My thoughts on how I do it manually

> - group nodes by dataSourceId
> - for each a, create a new row with empty values ( except for a )
> - fill b
> - if there already is a b, duplicate the row and replace the a with a    "covered" index
> - repeat for c
> - repeat for c-6 but c-6 depends on b-3 and b-3 depends on a-2 so you must set a rowspan for a-2
> - repeat for d
> - repeat for d-2 but d-2 depends on b-2. It must not duplicate the row because there is enough space in the c-3 row
> - repeat for e-1
> - repeat for e-2 but you must replace d-2 with an "empty" value ( set    all sources between parent key and own key to "empty" )
> - repeat for self-reference

Do you guys have any ideas how to solve this problem? I don't think that I need the final code, I just don't have any idea how to setup the algorithm... so any pseudo code / algorithm suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide the `structuredClone()` function definition, for your last snippet? ...so your example attempt will not error.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles I'm sorry, I'm using this function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone . I'm using Chrome and Node v18 ... maybe your browser does not support it yet?

Comment: Right—[I don't have v98 Chrome, nor v94 Firefox](https://caniuse.com/?search=structuredClone). So I ran a copy of your example with `function structuredClone (objectToClone) { return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectToClone)); };` at the very bottom and it now runs without error. :S

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles yes, it should not throw :D but the code is not complete yet, there are still things left to be done

Comment: There is no dependency relationship among `d`, `e`, and `self-reference`.  How do you choose their column order, alphabetic by source id?

Comment: @ScottSauyet that shouldn't matter that much. But the expected order would be the same as in `dataSourceIds`

Comment: D'oh!  Somehow I missed the fact that that even existed!

Comment: Does the a-e need to go across the top, i.e., label column headers? Or can they go down the side, label rows. Second question, does "self-reference" need to be it's own column? Or can it simply be a flag in the appropriate cell.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles each "dataSourceId" ( `"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "self-reference"` ) would represent its own column. You might have a look at the `drawn expected result` where I tried to create the expected HTML from the given nodes

Comment: @baitendbidz Let me clarify my question. I saw your expected result, and I ask—is it *necessary* that the `"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "self-reference"` go across the top as column headers? It looks easier to me to program and construct the table if the  `"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "self-reference"`  go down the left side, as row labels. Another way to ask is—can the table be rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise? Or—can each "dataSourceId" ( "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "self-reference" ) represent its own *row*.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles oh, I'm sorry! Now I understand... Unfortunately I need those datasources go across the top as column headers. I can't "rotate" the table :(

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles: If we can get the data into a format for the one, it's easy enough to transpose it to do the other.

Comment: You say that "a single node can only depend on nodes from one source", but is it also true that all nodes from one source can, jointly, only depend on nodes from one single source, or is that just an accident of the sample data?  For example, could we have `h-2` depend on `g-3` and `h-3` depend on `f-1`, where `h-2` and `h-3` are in source `h`, `g-3` is in `g` and `f-1` is in `f`?  Or could both `h`'s depend *only* on things in *either* `g` or `f`?

Comment: @ScottSauyet `h-2` in source `h` can only depend on either nodes in source `g` or nodes in source `f`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not 100% confidant that I have understood what the fully generalised data set you are working with might look like, but the code below will do the following:

- Parse an arbitrary list of nodes of any length and any dependency
  depth.
- Process any number of sources, in any order of dependency.

It currently assumes:

- Only root nodes can be self referencing.  This can be changed but it
  is not trivial to do so.
- Dependency source order is the same as a sort order of sources,
  currently alphabetic.  But this can easily be set rather than derived
  from the data, eg, as per one of your knowns above.
- While there can be multiple paths between nodes, there must not be
  any loops, eg, 'a' depends on 'b' on 'c' on 'a'.  This will cause an
  infinite loop.

The approach in the code is:

- Make a structured linked list of the nodes.
- Get the root nodes.
- Recursively parse the root nodes and their descendants.

There are some further explanatory comments in the code.

Let me know if you need anything fixed/changed.

```js
const nodes = [
    { dataSourceId: "a", id: "a-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: undefined, dependsOnNodes: [] },
    { dataSourceId: "a", id: "a-2", dependsOnDataSourceId: undefined, dependsOnNodes: [] },
    { dataSourceId: "a", id: "a-3", dependsOnDataSourceId: undefined, dependsOnNodes: [] },
    { dataSourceId: "b", id: "b-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: "a", dependsOnNodes: ["a-1"] },
    { dataSourceId: "b", id: "b-2", dependsOnDataSourceId: "a", dependsOnNodes: ["a-1"] },
    { dataSourceId: "b", id: "b-3", dependsOnDataSourceId: "a", dependsOnNodes: ["a-1", "a-2"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-1"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-2", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-3", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-4", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-5", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2", "b-3"] },
    { dataSourceId: "c", id: "c-6", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2", "b-3"] },
    { dataSourceId: "e", id: "e-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: "c", dependsOnNodes: ["c-1", "c-3"] },
    { dataSourceId: "e", id: "e-2", dependsOnDataSourceId: "c", dependsOnNodes: ["c-3"] },
    { dataSourceId: "self-reference", id: "a-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: "a", dependsOnNodes: ["a-1"] },
    { dataSourceId: "d", id: "d-1", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2"] },
    { dataSourceId: "d", id: "d-2", dependsOnDataSourceId: "b", dependsOnNodes: ["b-2"] },
    { dataSourceId: "d", id: "d-3", dependsOnDataSourceId: "c", dependsOnNodes: ["c-3"] }
];

//  Build a list of structured nodes
dataSourceIds = [];
list = [];
selfRefs = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++ ) {
    if ( nodes[i].dataSourceId == "self-reference" ) {
        selfRefs.push(nodes[i].id);
    } else {
        if ( ! dataSourceIds.includes(nodes[i].dataSourceId) ) dataSourceIds.push(nodes[i].dataSourceId);
        list.push([ nodes[i].id, nodes[i].dataSourceId, [], nodes[i].dependsOnNodes, undefined ]);
    }
}
dataSourceIds.sort()

//  A utility, given a node id return the structured node
function getListNode(id) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
        if ( list[i][0] == id ) return list[i];
    }
    return undefined;
}

//  Populate structured nodes with their structured parents
for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
    var parents = [];
    for ( var j = 0; j < list[i][3].length; j++ ) {
        parents.push(getListNode(list[i][3][j]));
    }
    list[i][3] = parents;
}

//  Populate structured nodes with their structured children
for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
    for ( var j = 0; j < list[i][3].length; j++ ) {
        list[i][3][j][2].push(list[i]);
    }
}

//  Get the structured nodes with no parents
treeRoots = [];
for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
    if ( list[i][3].length == 0 ) treeRoots.push(list[i]);
}

function spanner(node) {
    //  Calculate the row span required for a node, by recursively walking the tree for the node
    var span;
    if ( node[2].length == 0 ) {
        span = 1
        node[4] = span;
    } else {
        var span = 0;
        for ( var i = 0; i < node[2].length; i++ ) {
            span += spanner(node[2][i]);
        }
        node[4] = span
    }
    return span
}

//  Utility to print a tree root
function printTR(treeRoots) {
    var text = "";
    for ( var i = 0; i < treeRoots.length; i++ ) {
        text += printNT(treeRoots[i], 0);
    }
    return text;
}

//  Utility to space out fields, indent, etc.
function spacer(n) {
    var N = n * 4;
    var text = "";
    for ( var i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        text += "&nbsp;"
    }
    return text;
}

//  Utility to print a node tree
function printNT(node, depth) {
    var text = "";
    text += '<br>' + spacer(depth) + node[0] + spacer(1) + node[4] + spacer(1) + node[1];
    for ( var j = 0; j < node[2].length; j++ ) {
        text += printNT(node[2][j], depth + 1);
    }
    return text;
}

function tableTR(treeRoots) {
    //  Convert a root tree into a set of rows
    var text = "";
    for ( var i = 0; i < treeRoots.length; i++ ) {
        var textRoot = '<tr>' + tableNT(treeRoots[i], "").replaceAll("</tr>", "<td></td></tr>");
        //  Add in a self reference
        if ( selfRefs.indexOf(treeRoots[i][0]) != -1 ) {
            ndx = textRoot.indexOf("</td></tr>");
            text += textRoot.slice(0,ndx) + treeRoots[i][0] + textRoot.slice(ndx);
        } else {
            text += textRoot;
        }
    }
    return text;
}

function sourcePadding(parent, child) {
    //  Generate empty table cells when child source is more than one source away from parent source.
    //  $ is to end of row of sources.
    var text = "";
    if ( child == "$" ) {
        for ( var i = 1; i < dataSourceIds.length - dataSourceIds.indexOf(parent); i++ ) {
            text += '<td>' + '</td>';
        }
    } else if ( parent != child && parent != "" ) {
        for ( var i = 1; i < dataSourceIds.indexOf(child) - dataSourceIds.indexOf(parent); i++ ) {
            text += '<td>' + '</td>';
        }
    }
    return text;
}

function tableNT(node, parentSource) {
    //  Convert a node tree into table rows
    var text = "";
    if ( node[4] == 1 ) {
        if ( node[2].length == 1 ) {
            text += sourcePadding(parentSource, node[1]) + '<td>' + node[0] + '</td>' + tableNTfr(node[2][0], node[1]);
        } else {
            text += sourcePadding(parentSource, node[1]) + '<td>' + node[0] + '</td>' + sourcePadding(node[1], "$") + '</tr>';
        }
    } else {
        text += sourcePadding(parentSource, node[1]) + '<td rowspan="' + node[4] + '">' + node[0] + '</td>' + tableNTfr(node[2][0], node[1]);
        text += tableNTor(node[2][0], [ [ node[1], node[2][0][1] ] ]);
        for ( var i = 1; i < node[2].length; i++ ) {
            text += '<tr>' + tableNT(node[2][i], node[1])
        }
    }
    return text;
}

function tableNTfr(node, parentSource) {
    //  The first row in a row span
    var text = "";
    if ( node[4] == 1 ) {
        if ( node[2].length == 1 ) {
            text += sourcePadding(parentSource, node[1]) + '<td>' + node[0] + '</td>' + tableNTfr(node[2][0], node[1]);
        } else {
            text += sourcePadding(parentSource, node[1]) + '<td>' + node[0] + '</td>' + sourcePadding(node[1], "$") + '</tr>';
        }
    } else {
        text += sourcePadding(parentSource, node[1]) + '<td rowspan="' + node[4] + '">' + node[0] + '</td>' + tableNTfr(node[2][0], node[1]);
    }
    return text;    
}

function tableNTor(node, skips) {
    //  The other rows in a row span
    var text = "";
    var skipped = [ ...skips ];
    if ( node[2].length != 0 ) {
        if ( node[4] > 1 ) {
            skipped.push([ node[1], node[2][0][1] ]);
            text += tableNTor(node[2][0], skipped)
            for ( var i = 1; i < node[2].length; i++ ) {
                text += '<tr>'
                for ( var j = 0; j < skipped.length - 1; j++ ) {
                    text += sourcePadding(skipped[j][0], skipped[j][1], 0);
                }
                text += tableNT(node[2][i], node[1])
            }
        }
    }
    return text;
}

function tableHead(dataSourceIds) {
    text = "";
    for ( var i = 0; i < dataSourceIds.length; i++ ) {
        text += '<th>' + dataSourceIds[i] + '</th>';
    }
    text += '<th>' + 'self-reference' + '</th>';
    return '<tr>' + text + '</tr>';
}

function doStuff() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < treeRoots.length; i++ ) {
        spanner( treeRoots[i] );
    }
    var printerOne = document.getElementById("printerOne");
    printerOne.innerHTML = printTR( treeRoots );
    var treeTable = document.getElementById("treeTable");
    treeTable.innerHTML = tableHead(dataSourceIds) + tableTR(treeRoots);
}
```

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body onload="doStuff()">
<div>
Parsed nodes with calculated row spans and source:
<div id="printerOne">
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
Tree converted to table rows:<br>&nbsp;
<div>
<table id="treeTable">
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: hey there, thanks a lot for your reply. I see that `d-1` starts at row 8 but I would expect it to be in row 2 since it'S a child of b-2 and there is enough space for it in this row

Comment: I can make it do that, but that would then push c-2, c-3, etc, down two rows, because d-1 and d-2 are not dependent on any 'c's.  It is just  question of do you want skipped dependency sources sorted before or after non skipped dependency sources.

Comment: PS:   At present they are not sorted.  They appear in the same order and relative position as they are in the source data.

Comment: do you think my expected HTML result is wrong? if not, do you think it's possible to modify your solution to the expected HTML result?

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understand the rules behind your data.  However, if the rule to interpret the table is "a node to right of another node in the same row means the node to the right is dependent on the node to its left" then d-1 cannot be in the same row as c-2 and d-2 cannot be in the same row as c-3 because the source data does not contain that dependency.

Comment: d and c nodes are children of b nodes, they can exist in the same row :) ( if there is space left in that column )

Comment: Sorry but I do not understand.  I have added another row of node data, d-3 dependent on c-3. If d-1 and d-2 move up beside c-2 and c-3 how does someone reading the table know that they are not dependent on c-2 and c-3 when d-3 is?

Comment: `how does someone reading the table know ...` - yeah this is a drawback. You can't, users must know the data models. Users know that both c and d depend on b, the know that c and d are not related to each other

Comment: If there is information required to format the data in tha table which is NOT in the data then it is NOT possible to automate the formatting of the data. There will always be cases where any algorithm gets it "wrong".

Comment: I have put some example more general formats of this up on GitHub - see - https://github.com/petern0691/tree-as-html-table.git

Comment: I have fixed an oversight in the above code.  Table layout in the case of rowspans separated by skipped over sources.